# Is it possible to send push notifications to external mobile app from a Power Apps Flow?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

We are currently working on an internal app where one section will focus on sending alerts to a list of people in our org, either via email or via push notifications

Part of the set up is an external React Native app that is just a WebView that displays the app.

Is it possible to send "proper" push notifications to the specified users, that are using the external mobile app, using a flow? Or would I somehow need to integrate with Azure and Firebase?

I'll be honest, I haven't tried to integrate this and am looking at how large of a task this is, and I haven't been able to come up with anything in my searches.

Comment: You cannot send push notifications to external apps using standard push notification connection available in power automate. You will need some custom connector or service for this.